# Trouble after update

Tags: grub2, updates, 23.04

I'm running Ubuntu 23.04 and just made an update (basically answered yes without checking what it did) but after that, my PC will not start as I want(no internet, screen resolution bad etc).

At start, I can still find the older version in GRUB bootloader meny and then everything works the way it should.

Now I would like to find the difference and see why my PC doesnt work with the update. Where should I start looking?

Comment: The packages that were updated can be found by looking in /var/log/apt

Comment: Great! Thanks!   

So I checked: The main package was new kernel (linux-modules-6.2.0-1003-oracle) and it came with a bunch of nvdia-updates. Probably on eof those nvdia that makes my screen resolution go nuts.